# Dojo function not working on IE8

Tags: checkbox, internet-explorer-8, dojo, cross-browser

I have a piece of code to select/deselect all Dojo checkboxes using a single master checkbox (which acts as a toggle) that **works fine on firefox but doesn't on IE8**. I tried hard to find the issue but was clueless, can anybody help. Im attaching the code below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");

    dojo.ready(function() {
        var checkboxes = [];
        dojo.query('#waferCheck_cb input[type=checkbox]').forEach(function(node, index, arr){
        checkboxes.push(arr[index].id);
        var handle = dojo.connect(dijit.byId(arr[index].id), "onchange", function(evt){

            var cbClicked = evt.target.id;
            var cbStatus = dijit.byId(cbClicked).get("checked");
            setCBSelection(checkboxes,cbClicked,cbStatus );
            dojo.disconnect(handle);        
            });
        });
    });

    function setCBSelection(checkboxes,cb_Clicked, cb_Status) {
        var len = checkboxes.length;
        if(len > 0) {
            // get index of the checkbox clicked
            var cb_pos = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if(cb_Clicked == checkboxes[i]) {
                    cb_pos = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If Select All checkbox clicked, set the other checboxes accordingly
            if(cb_pos == 0) {
                for(var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                    dijit.byId(checkboxes[i]).set("checked", cb_Status);
                }
            } else {
                // If any other checkbox is clicked, set the Select All accordingly
                var allCBSameStatus = true;
                for(var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                    var curCBStatus = dijit.byId(checkboxes[i]).get("checked");
                    if(curCBStatus != cb_Status) {
                        allCBSameStatus = false;
                        break;
                    };
                }
                if(allCBSameStatus){
                    dijit.byId(checkboxes[0]).set("checked", cb_Status)
                }else{
                    if(cb_Status == false) {
                        dijit.byId(checkboxes[0]).set("checked", cb_Status)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe IE8 doesn't like missing semicolons.  I see 2 lines that are missing semicolons.

```
dijit.byId(checkboxes[0]).set("checked", cb_Status)
```

Comment: No, that is not the issue, just checked it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define `function setCBSelection(...)` before `dojo.ready(..)` (see below)? Maybe this helps as it is used before it was defined? If that doesn't help, it may be useful if you post some kind of error-message IE might throw...

```
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");

    function setCBSelection(checkboxes,cb_Clicked, cb_Status) {
        var len = checkboxes.length;
        if(len > 0) {
            // get index of the checkbox clicked
            var cb_pos = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if(cb_Clicked == checkboxes[i]) {
                    cb_pos = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If Select All checkbox clicked, set the other checboxes accordingly
            if(cb_pos === 0) {
                for(i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                    dijit.byId(checkboxes[i]).set("checked", cb_Status);
                }
            } else {
                // If any other checkbox is clicked, set the Select All accordingly
                var allCBSameStatus = true;
                for(i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                    var curCBStatus = dijit.byId(checkboxes[i]).get("checked");
                    if(curCBStatus != cb_Status) {
                        allCBSameStatus = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(allCBSameStatus){
                    dijit.byId(checkboxes[0]).set("checked", cb_Status);
                }else{
                    if(cb_Status === false) {
                        dijit.byId(checkboxes[0]).set("checked", cb_Status);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    dojo.ready(function() {
        var checkboxes = [];
        dojo.query('#waferCheck_cb input[type=checkbox]').forEach(function(node, index, arr){
        checkboxes.push(arr[index].id);
        var handle = dojo.connect(dijit.byId(arr[index].id), "onchange", function(evt){

            var cbClicked = evt.target.id;
            var cbStatus = dijit.byId(cbClicked).get("checked");
            setCBSelection(checkboxes,cbClicked,cbStatus );
            dojo.disconnect(handle);        
            });
        });
    });
```

Btw: you should always use `===` to compare with `0` or `false`... You can use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)  to let JSLint check your code which detacts many issues one doesn't see in the first place. Hope i could help you.